# How to use "asio4all.dll" without installing ASIO4ALL?

Tags: audio, dll, low-latency, asio

How to use the functions of "asio4all.dll" without installing ASIO4ALL? Is it possible or installing ASIO4ALL is mandatory in order to use audio with low latency?

I'm building an application that needs audio with low latency and it would be interesting if the end user did not need to install ASIO4ALL.

Comment: ASIO4ALL is a so called third party library. You need to ask the developer if you are allowed to do what you want, is it possible at all, and then how it can be achieved. The website says it's free to end user, but it might not be allowed to be redistributed. For low latency audio in Windows you also have WASAPI exclusive streams.

Comment: Note that DAWs like FL Studio are permitted to redistribute, so you at least have a chance at gaining permission.  I don't know much else about the legality of it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the contributions. Found that it is possible and very simple. Just load dynamic library (asio4all.dll) and then register it using [regsvr32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regsvr32). Once the DLL is registered the ASIO4ALL will be listed as one of the ASIO drivers, without the ASIO4ALL has been installed. Works perfectly. Now I need to see if it is possible to redistribute the DLLs. Thanks for the ideas!